# UK Fence Height

Tags: united-kingdom

What is permitted by law?

The neighbour has erected a 7'4'' high fence which is over 10' high in one stretch. Since we are 2' lower, this makes the fence 9'4'' high and 12' high.

What height does the law permit?

Notes (added due to questions in comments and answers):

The main fence is a solid wooden fence.

The addition to the top in the past 3 weeks is a tarpaulin with a wooden frame around it. It blocks light. That makes it 7'4'' high (9'4'' on our side).

About 2 years ago the 10' high section (12' on our side) was erected, which is a solid wood fence with a tarpaulin with a wooden frame around it about 5' over the top of the wooden fence. The latter is so high it is in front of our television aerial.

In 2014 he increased the solid wood part of the fence from 4' high (6' on our side) to 6' high (8' on our side). The original border for 40 years was 4' high (6' on our side).

The majority of the fence is between our property and the neighbour's property. However, there is about a 1 to 2 metres stretch which is adjacent to the pavement which is facing the road. (That bit does impede our sightline when leaving the drive.)

Comment: Which part of the UK - E&W or Scotland?

Comment: South of England

Comment: It is a solid fence. The addition to the top in the past 3 weeks is a tarpaulin with a wooden frame around it. It blocks light. In 2014 he increased the solid wood part of the fence from 4' (6' on our side) to 6' (8' on our side). About 2 year ago the 10' section (12' on our side) was erected, which is a solid wood fence with a tarpaulin with a wooden frame around it about 5' over the top. The latter is so high it is in front of our television aerial. I will put this in the main question.

Comment: The maximum fence height allowed without planning permission is 2 metres, but permission can be obtained retrospectively. But: [Owners of luxury hotel ordered to tear down 6ft 6in fence after neighbours complained it was deliberately put up to annoy them](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3322372/Owners-luxury-hotel-ordered-tear-6ft-6in-fence-neighbours-complained-deliberately-annoy-them.html).

Answer (score 1):

It depends where the fence is. For fences facing a public road the maximum is 1m. For fences not facing a public road you can go up to 2m. Higher is possible but requires planning permission.

This applies to hedges too.

Comment: Can you please cite the laws which specify these limits.

Comment: OP: It is a border fence between two properties, but a small part of it faces a public road, next to a pavement. So it exceeds both heights. (I will add this information to the OP.)

Comment: @DavidSiegel: [The Town and Country Planning (General Permitted Development) (England) Order 2015](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2015/596/schedule/2/part/2/crossheading/class-a-gates-fences-walls-etc/made).